# how can I arrange these functions to be high-order

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

Rather than having the following 2 string functions and calling them both

```
removeTrailingSlash = (site) => site.replace(/\/$/, "");

getLastPartOfURL = (url) => url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

I was hoping to be able to combine them into one high-order function definition

```
removeTrailingSlash = (site) => site.replace(/\/$/, "");

getLastPartOfURL = site => removeTrailingSlash => url => url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

So I guess I am unclear how i can use arrow functions to do this or if there is a more elegant approach. Thanks.

Comment: https://babeljs.io/repl will translate the code into es5 syntax, I'm sure you'll find your errors then; hint: removeTrailingSlash in your code's last line is not what you think

Comment: could you plz put your input string and expected output/outputs?

Comment: I don't get what's wrong with the first code. What do you mean by "and calling them both" - where are you calling them and how?

Comment: Why is one parameter called `site` and the other `url`? Shouldn't they represent the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A higher order function is a function that takes a function as an argument and/or returns a function.

This answer assumes you want to understand higher-order functions more (hence the title) and are not just looking for a better way to get the last part of a path (because this probably isn't it).

In your second example:

```
getLastPartOfURL = site => removeTrailingSlash => url => url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

I read that `getLastPartOfURL` will be a function takes an argument `site` and returns a function that takes and argument `removeTrailingSlash` that returns a function that takes an argument `url` and then returns a substring of that url. Notice, that most of the arguments you passed in to these function (`site`, `removeTrailingSlash`) were not used.

For an arrangement like this, you can instead pass actual functions into those arguments and then compose the functions at the end for your final result.

For example:

```js
//define a few simple functions
const removeTrailingSlash = (url) => url.replace(/\/$/, "");
const getLast = (url) => url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') +1 )

// define a higher order function that expects functions as arguments and composes them
const getLastPartOfURL = removeTrailingSlashFN => getLastFN => url => getLastFN(removeTrailingSlash(url))

// call it by passing in functions and url:

let result = getLastPartOfURL(removeTrailingSlash)(getLast)("http://www.example.com/test/")
console.log(result)

/* Notice that this arrangement allows you to make function partials! */

let partial = getLastPartOfURL(removeTrailingSlash)(getLast)
// now you only need to pass in url
console.log(partial("http://www.example.com/foo/"))
console.log(partial("http://www.example.com/bar/"))
```

There are a lot of other patterns, but hopefully this helps.

Comment: cool thanks. This isn't the way I expected to call getLastPartOfURL, but I think my question reflects my confusion of this pattern. @bambam's advice to use babel tool to translate to es5 helped me realize my flawed thought process.

Answer (score 1):

You already have a decent answer about higher-order functions, but I think the concept you might actually be looking for is *function composition*.  Composition lets you define a new function that is the result of passing the result of one function into the input of another, like this:

```js
const compose = (f, g) => x => f(g(x));

// Your original functions
const removeTrailingSlash = url => url.replace(/\/$/, "");
const getLast             = url => url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

const both = compose(getLast, removeTrailingSlash);

console.log(both('http://www.example.com/foo/'));
console.log(both('http://www.example.com/bar/'));

// You can even do another composition for logging
const logBoth = compose(console.log, both);
logBoth('http://www.example.com/foo/');
logBoth('http://www.example.com/bar/');
```

Note in this particular case, it is `compose` that is actually the higher order function.  It takes two functions `f` and `g` as parameters and returns a new function as a result.  The new combined function, `both`, isn't itself considered a higher-order function, even though it was created using one.  It takes a string as a parameter and returns a string.

Also note that while you can define compose yourself as I did above, it is general purpose enough to be [already included](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#compose) in libraries like Ramda.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're expecting to get an output of `bar` from an input of something like `https://google.com/foo/bar/`.

If that is the case then I recommend something like this.

```
url.split('/').filter(Boolean).pop();
```

This will split up your url into an array based on where the slashes are (in the example case it will be `['https:', '', 'google.com', 'foo', 'bar', '']`), then it will filter out all of the empty strings, and then return the last item in the array (`bar`)

If you really want them to be different functions then I recommend something like [Method chaining](https://schier.co/blog/2013/11/14/method-chaining-in-javascript.html) so you'll be able to do something like:

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you need a function that gets the last part of the url that ends with `/`.

```js
const getLastPart = url => url.match(/\/(\w*)\/$/)[1];

const p = getLastPart('part1/part2/part3/');
console.log(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect<sup>1</sup> you just want `getLastPartOfURL` to call `removeTrailingSlash` before it returns:

```js
const removeTrailingSlash = (url) => url.replace(/\/$/, '');
const getLastPartOfURL = (url) => {
    const noTrailing = removeTrailingSlash(url);    // call removeTrailingSlash
    return noTrailing.substr(noTrailing.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
};

const tests = [
  'http://www.example.com',
  'www.example.com/foo',
  'http://www.example.com/foo/bar',
  'http://www.example.com/foo/bar/',
  'www.example.com/foo/index.html',
];

console.log(JSON.stringify(tests.map(getLastPartOfURL)));
```

<sup>1: A [Higher-Order Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) is a function that takes a function as a parameter, or returns a function as its output.</sup>